# can I load dependencies in a separate folder other than node_modules via package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

When I run this I am downloading all the dependencies in the node_modules directory

```
{
  "name": "bootstrap-test-app",
  "engine": "node 5.5.0",
  "engineStrict": false,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "master.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "author": "soum",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "latest",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "requirejs": "2.1.22"
  }
}
```

My question is it possible to set a path for the dependencies instead of node_modules
for example lets say in a dorectory called "dependencies"? Can I set a destination 
property relative to the root of project so that my file structure looks like this

```
my-app
  package.json
  dependencies
    -bootstrap-sass
    -jquery
    -requirejs
  node_modules
```

Comment: I usually always copy stuff like bootstrap, jquery, and stuff like that into a folder called public and set that as my static content folder in my app.js file. You can do this if you want but dependencies will run from node_modules folder thanks to the Node runtime

Comment: @KeplerIO -- Good point. I guess I can just move the bootstrap manually because we will be adding overrides to it...so I guess after pulling it down I can just remove bootstrap as a dependency from the json and keep the rest and add the node_modules in gitignore. Thanks for the idea

Comment: you can pull it from node_modules into your new folder you want but don't remove it from node_modules after. It can cause issues in your app since Node looks at your package.json file then checks node_modules to load code correctly. Putting dependencies on this new folder is only really helpful for linking say bootstrap to your main layout.html file

Comment: @KeplerIO -- yeah makes sense

Comment: Bower is used to manage front-end dependencies with gulp to migrate libraries to public folder. check this out http://andy-carter.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-package-manager-bower-and-using-gulp-to-manage-components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible now and it is very unlikely to be possible in the future.

See this issue on GitHub from 2013 and the comments there:

- [Issue #3597: npm install into arbitrary folder instead of node_modules](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3597)

The future of that can be summarize by two quotes from that discussion:

1. "Is there any way to change the location where the node_modules folder gets installed for local installed dependencies...??"
2. "no, there is not, and there are no plans to implement such a feature."

See also an older issue from 2011:

- [Issue #775: node_modules directory location](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/775)

What you can do is to create a directory that you want and a symlink called `node_modules` with something like that:

```
$ mkdir dependencies
$ ln -sv dependencies node_modules
‘node_modules’ -> ‘dependencies’
$ npm i tryjson -S
customdeps@1.0.0 /home/rsp/node/test/customdeps
└── tryjson@1.1.4 
$ ls dependencies
tryjson
```

I just came up with that idea. I wasn't sure if npm can install in a symlinked directory but I just tested it and it turns out that it can.

Of course to actually use those dependencies in Node, you'd have to set the `NODE_PATH` environment variable accordingly. See:

- https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html